# how to customize MoviePlayer of UIWebView

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiwebviewdelegate

Hi I want to add some custom controls like a UIButton on movieplayer of UIWebView when it is loaded from that webview. Is there any possible way to access the movieplayer of uiwebview or override it with normal MPMoviePlayerController.

**UPDATE**

ok you can access it as follows first add notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(VideoEnterFullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

and then

```
-(void)VideoEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification*)notification
```

{

```
 id moviePlayer = notification.object;  
 NSLog(@"");
```

}

But the problem is I cannot access any properties of this object that is **UIMoviePlayerController**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open-source project here: https://github.com/blizzard-op/VideoPlayerKit

You can initialize it by: `[VideoPlayerKit initWithContainingViewController:optionalTopView:hideTopViewWithControls:];`

The optional properties are shown on the link I provided.

Comment: How can I use it with webview play YouTube video?

Comment: You mean playing a youtube video with apple's UIWebView?

Comment: yeah, i want to play youtube video in uiwebview

Comment: I know exactly how to do that... first you will need to start a new question then tag me in a comment so I know where your question is. I can answer it there. I have it at the tip of my tongue. I can answer it immediately. I have used many times

Comment: My Question link 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825534/webview-playback-control-programmatically-for-youtube-video-in-ios/24837789#24837789](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825534/webview-playback-control-programmatically-for-youtube-video-in-ios/24837789#24837789)