# Webview playback control programmatically for YouTube video in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

In My App, User can open YouTube from UIWebview, I got notification when plays video in full screen, but I can't get control programmatically like mpmovieplayer controller to pause, play, stop.

How can I get it in webview?

Comment: You can try to do it in JavaScript (search the DOM for the video element or something, and control that) and then inject the JavaScript code into the web view with `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"<javascript here>"];`

Comment: I am new in javascript, so can you give me any reference url for getting control of the play YouTube video.

Comment: Here's the [Video tag reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp), so once you've found the video element you can call `play()` or `pause()`... Maybe this will work: `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].pause();"];`

Comment: [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('video')[‌​0].pause();"];  

The above code doesn't work while I call it when play video in full screen view.

Comment: Are you trying to pause a currently playing fullscreen video? What triggers the action in your app?

Comment: Yes, I want to pause a currently playing full screen video, but this code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(VideoExitFullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(VideoEnterFullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

and for catch the full screen

```
#pragma mark - UIMoviePlayerController notification handle

- (void)VideoExitFullScreen:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Exit from Full Screen..");
}

- (void)VideoEnterFullScreen:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"Enter in Full Screen..");
   [web goBack];  //back to notmal webview.. or pause the video
}
```

Comment: you can also get the movieplayercontroller current state by using NSNotifcation instead of id >> notification.userInfo

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to stop the music load the "" url to web view. So it will stop.

This is the code:

```
   [_Music_WbView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@""]]]];
    _Music_WbView.hidden = YES;
   if([_Music_WbView retainCount] > 0)
 {
      [_Music_WbView release];
      _Music_WbView = nil;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Link of Youtube Video"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
[myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```